# Pushing array into array and using it throws NaN

Tags: javascript, arrays, nan, extendscript

I've got a variable called colorHM:

```
var colorHM = "50,50,74,255,100,255,4,3,50".
```

Now I'm using this snippet here to cut it into pieces with the following scheme:  `R,g,b,R,g,b,R,g,b`, and again to `var a = R,g,b` and `var b = R,g,b` etc...

```
var firstColorHM = colorHM.split(",", 3);
firstColorHM = firstColorHM.toString();
var firstColorHMA = firstColorHM.split(",");
firstCMA.push(firstColorHMA[0]);
firstCMA.push(firstColorHMA[1]);
firstCMA.push(firstColorHMA[2]);
```

But using it to calculate `distance = eDist(firstCMA, firstCTA)` gives me `NaN`.

```
function eDist (col1, col2) {
    var rmean = ((col1[0] + col2[0]) / 2);
    var dR = (col1[0] - col2[0]);
    var dG = (col1[1] - col2[1]);
    var dB = (col1[2] - col2[2]);

    return Math.sqrt((2 + (rmean / 256)) * Math.pow(dR, 2) + (4 * Math.pow(dG, 2)) + ( 2 + ((255- rmean) / 256)) * Math.pow(dB, 2));
}
```

Using `firstCMA.push(10); firstCMA.push(20); firstCMA.push(30);` instead of `firstCMA.push(firstColorHMA[0]);..` makes it work again.

The variable `firstCTA` is left out, but parsed the same way.
I simply checked if the Arrays were working by trying to call different indexes from the array, which worked.

Why does pushing numbers work but pushing `firstColorHMA[0]` doesnt?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please create a runnable snippet from your code demonstrating your issue (click "edit" below your question, then click `<>` icon above your edit frame).

Comment: `firstColorHMA[0]` (and the other parts) is a string and not a number, hence `firstCMA` is an array of strings (`["50", "50", "74"])`. `col1[0] + col2[0]` will also be a string.

Comment: @Andreas The function `.split` returns an array if im not mistaken?

Comment: Yes. An array of strings.

Comment: Try something like this: `const [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i] = colorHM.split(',').map(Number)` Your current code does a split and then a toString and then pushes to a non existing variable named `firstCMA`, it is totally unclear what you're trying to do based on the code provided.

Comment: @HMR Destructuring is nice but 9 variables for this is a little bit overkill... Just grab/slice the numbers you need from the big array.

Comment: @HMR To answer your question, firstCMA is used here: `distance = eDist(firstCMA, firstCTA);`, Sorry forgot to mention that line. Thanks for all the help tho! It works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the comments says, when you split() a string, the generated array will contain strings:

> The split() method splits a String object **into an array of strings** by separating the string into substrings, using a specified separator string to determine where to make each split.

So actually the array `firstColorHMA` holds numbers as strings, an easy fix to this, will be using the `unary plus` to cast the array items to numbers, like this:

```
firstCMA.push(+firstColorHMA[0]);
firstCMA.push(+firstColorHMA[1]);
firstCMA.push(+firstColorHMA[2]);
```

Or alternatively, use a more explicit logic like:

```
firstCMA.push(Number(firstColorHMA[0]));
firstCMA.push(Number(firstColorHMA[1]));
firstCMA.push(Number(firstColorHMA[2]));
```